# Have to print frequency in sorted array. My solution have bug, How to fix it?

Tags: java, arrays

I have to count how many times an integer is occurring in a sorted array.

Expected Input:

```
int[] arr = {10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 40, 40, 45, 45}
```

Expected Output:

```
10 - 3

20 - 2

40 - 2

45 - 2
```

So, I used for loop which is starting from first(i) index and comparing it with((i-1)which is 0 index) element if it is equal then increment value of counter if it is not equal then printing answer and set value of counter at 1.

But this solution is not giving me output of arr[arr.length - 1] element. Why?

My Output:

```
10 - 3

20 - 2

40 - 2
```

My Solution -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Frequencies in a sorted array
    int[] arr = {10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 40, 40, 45, 45};
    get_Frequencies(arr);
}

public static void get_Frequencies(int[] arr) {
    int counter = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
            counter++;
        }

        if (arr[i] != arr[i - 1]) {
            System.out.println(arr[i - 1] + " - " + counter);
            counter = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to run your program with a debugger and go through it step by step. This will show you where the execution deviates from your expectations.

Comment: You hit the end of your loop, the last number was 45, but you never loop again to compare that last 45 to anything. So those results need to be manually printed after the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you exited the loop, the count of last integer won't be printed. You have to print it after exiting the loop.

Code -

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  //Frequencies in a sorted array
  int[] arr = {10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 40, 40, 45, 45};
   get_Frequencies(arr);
}

public static void get_Frequencies(int[] arr) {
   int counter = 1;
   int i = 1;
   for(; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
        counter++;
     }

     if (arr[i] != arr[i - 1]) {
       System.out.println(arr[i - 1] + " - " + counter);
       counter = 1;
    }
  }

  System.out.println(arr[i - 1] + " - " + counter);
 }
}
```